# Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>List</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Javascript code -->
<script>
         function showUser(str) {
         if (str == " ") {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = " ";
         return;
         } else {
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         } else {
         // code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
         }
         };
         xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
         xmlhttp.send();
         }
        }
</script>
        <!-- CSS for HTML table -->
<style>
    table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    }

    th {text-align: left;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option value=" ">Select a person:</option>
            <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
            <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
            <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
            <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
       </select>   
   </form>
    <div id="txtHint">Result from PHP script should appear here</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I run the following HTML page in the Google Chrome Browser via Netbeans, I am met with this error (see Title) when I try to select a person from the list.

> xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()

This line of code and the one below seems to be the areas of concern based on Chrome's Developer tools.

> select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)

Can anyone pinpoint what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right underneath:

```
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
```

Add:

`xmlhttp = new XmlHttpRequest();`

That way, you'll satisfy web browsers with javascript engines that have XMLHttpRequest defined.

Also, xmlhttp needs to have a valid value (handle) before `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()` can be properly executed.

If your browser (especially very old IE browsers) is still picky then change `xmlhttp` to `var xmlhttp` since var before a variable name means to define a new variable.

Comment: Thank you. I believe you are correct. But as for the (handle) point, what exactly do you mean by this? I'm relatively new to this, so apologies if it's not obvious to me.

Comment: I forgot to tag you in my comment above.

Comment: a handle is an old-fashioned term that means a resource. You know when you do x=y, you're setting the variable x to be the value of y. but if y was something more special than just a regular numerical value then its what I'd like to call a handle but in reality it is an object.

Comment: Thank you. I get what you mean.

Comment: sorry to ask, but what would you suggest that I add to the code to solve the issue with the function? As in what object should I add to the code and where? Any help would be much appreciated.